# Words that changed meaning in past hundred years

Tags: meaning, etymology, history, language-change

I am looking for a list of words that were used to mean something different from for what they are used now.

- some words are such that whose meaning has changed completely and
- some words have more than one meaning, but earlier one meaning was in popular use and nowadays another meaning is in popular use.

I am posting two links [here](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/words-literally-changed-meaning-through-2173079) and [here](http://ideas.ted.com/2014/06/18/20-words-that-once-meant-something-very-different/), both talk about the change of meaning of some words over a period of some hundreds of years, but I am only interested in past **one hundred years** period, not older than that.

In case if it is too much for you to type to explain the earlier meaning and recent meaning, you can just type the word, I will try to find the two usages.

Comment: You can find a few in this  interesting link: http://aggslanguage.wordpress.com/semantic-change/

Comment: You should start off with slang, for example the  term *bitch* usually referred to a female dog, then its derogatory meaning became predominate but always referred to women. Finally, today, the term can be used for both sexes.

Comment: This is an "nice" paper on [semantic reversal](http://www.scribd.com/doc/29025207/change-of-meaning). List type questions are OT here, though.

Comment: A modern-day list http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/02/26/words-that-have-changed-meaning_n_4847343.html I think your question is "too broad", there are literally hundreds of words that have changed their meanings in the last thirty years, let alone one hundred.

Comment: 'Insegrevious', which many would consider a word, possibly changes meaning every time it's used: insegrevious; insegreviate; insegreviously: a catch-all word meaning “anything you want it to mean!" [M-W]

Comment: What a great question -- reference needed of words with particular meaning change over the century.  Since, what, maybe 1 question in 50 is on topic here .. this question is not only the rare on-topic question but it's also super-interesting.  Thanks, @Vikram !

Comment: "broad" ?  if the answer is a **long** list, that has no connection to "broadness" of the question.  this question could not be more specific and clear.  BTW @Mari, you assert that "100s of words" (how many? state it? do you mean 500? 10,000? 120?  state please) have changed meaning since 1900.  For me that is **very interesting information** and I truly thank you for it.  (If someone asked me :How many words have changed meaning since 1900" I literally would not know with three! orders of magnitude.)  So your information is astounding.  Please give me the reference, thanks!

Comment: There are a couple links here to "slang" words that have, i suppose you could say, "changed meaning".  (ie: every single slang word is a case of "change of meaning".)  This seems like a highly uninteresting case of words "changing meaning."

Comment: don't thank me, it's your great question.

Comment: @Vikram The movie you're looking for is [The Sleeping Dictionary](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0242888/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_43)

Comment: @madmada, thank you friend, I appreciate your effort

Answer (score 4):

How about these:

- [Harbinger](http://wordsmith.org/words/harbinger.html)
- [Obsequious](http://wordsmith.org/words/obsequious.html)
- [Restive](http://wordsmith.org/words/restive.html)
- [Garble](http://wordsmith.org/words/garble.html)
- [Pabulum](http://wordsmith.org/words/pabulum.html)
- [Beldam](http://wordsmith.org/words/beldam.html)
- [Prude](http://wordsmith.org/words/prude.html)
- [Quantum](http://wordsmith.org/words/quantum.html)
- [Sycophant](http://wordsmith.org/words/sycophant.html)
- [Meticulous](http://wordsmith.org/words/meticulous.html)

Some of these may not be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: These are absolutely amazing!  How did you know that Mathias?  Harbinger!

Comment: It's interesting that some are "soft" meaning change.  For example, apparently "obsequious" meant "dutiful" but it has come to mean "dutiful suck-up".  So, that's a **"strong change of tone"**.  For example, it would appear that "restive" has literally **reversed** meaning.  It would be interesting to find words that just "changed meaning altogether!" (to a totally different field, as it were!)